# sed replace issue

Tags: shell-script, sed

My file contains

```
$Param_T=ABC49_SA_T2
$Param_V=ABC49BC_SA_V2
$Param_ST=ABC491_SA_M2
```

I am trying to replace a value starts with ABC*_ with XYZ12_

```
sed -i 's/ABC\.*_/XYZ12_/g' INCR.parm
```

Above is the sed command i have used. It is not throwing any error but value is not changing.Could someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

With sed, the way to implement non-greedy matching is to specify a set of character you *don't* want to match:

```
sed -i 's/=ABC[^_]*_/=XYZ12_/g' INCR.parm
```

That is: match "ABC" followed by zero or more non-underscore characters followed by underscore.

And note, you don't escape the dot. A "bare" dot means "match any character"; an escaped dot means "match a literal dot". You weren't making any replacements because none of the data matches the literal string "ABC."

Comment: You _might_ want to match the `=` as well, or the start of the word `ABC` in some other way (`\<`).  Otherwise they will do weird things to lines like `...=BOOABC09_...`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont escape the "`.`" that matches all characters [ **Greedy**]

```
sed -i 's/ABC.*_/XYZ12_/g' INCR.parm
```

Output:

```
$Param_T=XYZ12_T2
$Param_V=XYZ12_V2
$Param_ST=XYZ12_M2)
```

If you want to replace ABC* only uptill first underscore ( `_` ) [Lazy], you need to use perl regex

use

```
perl -pe  's/ABC(.*?)_/XYZ12_/g' INCR.parm
```

Output:

```
$Param_T=XYZ12_SA_T2
$Param_V=XYZ12_SA_V2
$Param_ST=XYZ12_T2
```

> '**Greedy**' means match longest possible string.
>
> '**Lazy**' means match shortest possible string.

Comment: Thanks for this..It worked. But have some issue when there is a tab or space before $Param* (sample " $Param_T=ABC12_T2") . Value is not getting replaced.

Comment: I dont think so it should be a problem, can you update the question with the exact values you need to get replaced , i tried with your sample and its working for me

Comment: "    $Param_STG_V=DTST49_SA_STG_RKEM2_V"
"    $Param_SIM_T=DTST49_SA_SIM_RKEM2"
"    $Param_SIM_V=DTST49_SA_SIM_RKEM2_V"
"    $Param_WRK_T=DTST49_TMP_LOAD_UTILITY"
Above is my sample data, I have to replace with DTST49 with DDEV25,

Comment: have added quotes as it is not accepting space or tab before

Comment: urplease edit the question and add your sample, as it is not very clear

Comment: The `.` expression can not be "greedy" by itself, but `.*` is, as is `\.*` (at least when it comes to matching dots).